# nginx nested location try_files priority

Tags: nginx, configuration

What is actual order of applying rules like: index,location,try_files ?

Configuration:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    listen [::1]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /www/public;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Expected behavior:

1. uri=http://localhost/test.php
2. match "location /"
3. try_files test.php not
4. try_files test.php/ not
5. try_files /index.php match
6. match nested "location ~ \.php$"

Actual behavior:

1. uri=http://localhost/test.php
2. match nested "location ~ \.php$"

Did i expect wrong behavior?

**Edited:**

So i have to try_files in every location section?

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php; # added line
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actual behaviour is how it works. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details. The main exception is the rewrite module (`if`, `set`, `rewrite` and `return` directives) which may be evaluated before the `location` is selected.

Comment: So i have to add try_files for php also?

Comment: Yes. And it is also best practice to [avoid passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).